# Trying to show some ASCII art line by line in a Command Prompt window, but the window closes after the first line is displayed. How do I fix this?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

Trying to show the ASCII art text "Hotdog Water" (don't ask) line by line, and it's not working. The Command Prompt window closes after the first line has been displayed.

My code is in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/DJMoffinz/98888c65339f6c1fc978076874c1b563).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pipes `|` and closing parentheses `)` require escpaping with a caret. `^`.  IE: `^|` or `^)`

Comment: @T3RR0R - in this case it will work without escaped `)` but it's a good practice.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code:

```
@echo off

echo   _    _       _      _              __          __   _            
timeout 1 > nul
echo  | |  | |     | |    | |             \ \        / /  | |           
timeout 1 > nul
echo  | |__| | ___ | |_ __| | ___   __ _   \ \  /\  / /_ _| |_ ___ _ __ 
timeout 1 > nul
echo  |  __  |/ _ \| __/ _` |/ _ \ / _` |   \ \/  \/ / _` | __/ _ \ '__|
timeout 1 > nul
echo  | |  | | (_) | || (_| | (_) | (_| |    \  /\  / (_| | ||  __/ |   
timeout 1 > nul
echo  |_|  |_|\___/ \__\__,_|\___/ \__, |     \/  \/ \__,_|\__\___|_|   
timeout 1 > nul
echo                                __/ |                               
timeout 1 > nul
echo                               |___/                                
timeout 1 > nul
pause
```

you need to escape some special symbols - in your case pipes. Try like this:

```
echo   _    _       _      _              __          __   _            
timeout 1 > nul
echo  ^| ^|  ^| ^|     ^| ^|    ^| ^|             \ \        / /  ^| ^|           
timeout 1 > nul
echo  ^| ^|__^| ^| ___ ^| ^|_ __^| ^| ___   __ _   \ \  /\  / /_ _^| ^|_ ___ _ __ 
timeout 1 > nul
echo  ^|  __  ^|/ _ \^| __/ _` ^|/ _ \ / _` ^|   \ \/  \/ / _` ^| __/ _ \ '__^|
timeout 1 > nul
echo  ^| ^|  ^| ^| (_) ^| ^|^| (_^| ^| (_) ^| (_^| ^|    \  /\  / (_^| ^| ^|^|  __/ ^|   
timeout 1 > nul
echo  ^|_^|  ^|_^|\___/ \__\__,_^|\___/ \__, ^|     \/  \/ \__,_^|\__\___^|_^|   
timeout 1 > nul
echo                                __/ ^|                               
timeout 1 > nul
echo                               ^|___/                                
timeout 1 > nul
pause
```

Pipe expects a commands on both of its sides and will output from the first command to the second. And so cmd tries to executes them - if the executed command fails (e.g. `_`) the whole script will exit. To escape the special characters use carret - `^`