# Batch (.bat or cmd) script crashes when trying to print my ASCII art

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ascii-art

My code crashes when trying to print this ASCII image:

```bash
:91
title 911 turbo
echo please turn on fullscreen and wait...
timeout 5
echo 55555555555555555555555555555555555555555YYJJ???777777777777????JJJJJJYYYYYY555YY555YYY555PPPGGBBBP5PGGPP5PPGGGGGPGGGGGGPGGGGGGBB#
echo PPPPPPP55555555555555555555555555YJ?7~^:::.:^!7?Y55PGGBB#######&&&&&#####BGGP5555555555PPPPPPPPPGBBGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBBBBGBBBBBBBBBB##
echo PPPPPPPPPPPP555555555555555555?!^^::::::..YG######&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&####BB#BPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPGGGGBBBBBBBBB##################BB###
echo PPPPPPPPP55PPPP555555555PP5Y?!~!~~~^^^:!~!#PGGGGGGGGGGGGG#&&&&&&&&#BBBBGBGGGBBP55PPPPPPPP5PPPPGGBBBBB##B#######&###&&&#&&#########
echo GPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP555555?77!!Y:....:::7:~BGPGGGGBBBGGBB#&&&&&&&&#&&BBBBBBBGGBBG5Y5PPPPGGGGGGGBBBBBBB#########&####&&&&&&&&#####&&
echo GGGPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP555?77~:.!7.....:.~~:^GBGGBBBBBBB#&&&&&&&&&&&##&&BGGBBBGGGBBGP5J5PPGGP55PGBBBBBBBB#####&####&&&&&&###&###&&&&&
echo PPPPPPP55555Y555555YYJ!7~:..:?^.....:^7^.^5GGBGBBBBB###B&&&&&&&&&&B#&&#&&&&#####&B##GGBBBJ7Y5PGBBBBBBBBBBB#BBBB##&&&#####&##&&&&&&
echo PPP555555555~:^7?7!~^.7^....^7:...:^~!?J:~5GPBGGGBBBBBBBBBBBBGPP#BBGGGBBBBBB###BYY55P55JY5J55555P55PBBBBBBBBBBB###&#########&&&&&&
echo PPPPP5555555J77???J7. ..::::^^:::^^~~~7J7!7?JJJJ?77!!~~~~^^^^^^~7????????77?777!:.......::^^:......:^^~!?JYPGB#######&&########&&#
echo PPPPPPPPPP555P5Y?~:.                  .::...     ...........:::::::::::::::::.::::::::::::::::::..        .:!J5PB#BB###BBBBBBGGBBB
echo PPPPPPPPPPPPY7^....  ..  :!^.                                ....^!!!~^:::::::^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^:.     .!?Y5YYPPPGPPP5P5PP5555P
echo GGGPPPPPPP5!^:. ....?5^..:::............. ....  .    ...        :7JYYJY?~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!!!!!!!!~~^.   .!PP5?YYY5555YYJJJ??YJY5
echo GPPP5555YY?GBP5J: .?P7:.:::::::::::::::::.:....:!!~:.....   .. .^?P5JJY5J?7777!!!!!!!!!777777777777777!~^:!?5JJJYPPPPPPPPPP5555555
echo PPPGGGGGBYBBPP5J5:.~^. .::::::::::::::::::::..JBBGP57:.... .::.:!YYYY?5PP5YJJ???777777777?7JJ????????????JJY5PPBBBGPPPPPPPPGGGGGGG
echo &&&&&###J7B5PJ?G?5::::.:::::::::::::::::::::.J#G55Y?!~^.::.:::::!J55PGGGPYYJJYJJJJJJJJJJJYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY555P5PPPYJYPPPPPPPPPPPPP
echo BBGGGGGP!7P5P?^!^P!~~~~~:::::::::::::::::::::GGJJY?PP:.:^^^:....:!?JYYYJJJJJJJYYJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJYYYYYY55PPPPPPPPPPPGGGGGG
echo GGGGGPPPY75YPJ?77P5^7!~~~:::::::::::::::::::~G5?J:^G?.^^:^::..::.::^~!7???JJYYYYYYYYYYYY55555555PPPPPGGGGGGGGGB&@@#B#GPPPPGPPPGGGG
echo GGGGPPPPP5Y!!!~!.5#!!7!~^^^:::::::::::::::::~PJ5JJ!^~7G5^^!~^!J?!?5PPGGPGPB&&&BGGPPGPGGGGGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBBBBBBB##&#B#BPPPPPPPPPPPGG
echo PPPPP5555P7  ~~!YB&5~?7!~^::^^^^^^::::::::::~P55JJ77~^?Y!^!!^^~~~!JY5555PPGB#BGPPGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGBBBBB#########&B?77???Y555PPP
echo GPPPPPPPPP5. .:!G#&&J5P5YJ77!~~^^^^^::::::^:^5!!!7::^77JJ!~7~^^:^^~!?5PGGGGGGBBBBBBB###########&&&&&&&&&&&&@@@@@&&&&G55555PPPPPPPP
echo PPPPP555555J:.:~B&&@&#&&#BBBGPP5555YYJ??7!!~~5^.:JP!7YP5YB~77!~^^~~7YPGGBBB&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&#BBBBBBBBBBBB##
echo 55555555555PPYP#&@@@@@@@&##&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&###BY...!?7J~!B&G7??7!!!7JPGBBBBB########&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&@@@@@@@@@&&##########&&&&&&&&
echo 5555555555555PPGGGGBBBBBBBBB#############&&&&&#5^   .:7G&&@&###BB##&&&&&&&&&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
echo 5555555555YYYYYYYYJYYYYYJYYYYYYYYY555555PPPPPPGGGY7!75#&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
pause >nul
```

I tried researching everything, and could not find answers.

Comment: There are one heck of a lot of existing questions and answers, which deal with `echo` and special characters like `&`. You should also do something about your `^` characters, I would also make sure you turn off delayed expansion for your `!` characters too.

Comment: duplicates: [Can't echo ASCII art with `._|_`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35855062/995714), [How to store ASCII Art into a variable in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70379741/995714), https://stackoverflow.com/q/19174465/995714, https://stackoverflow.com/q/54953893/995714, https://stackoverflow.com/q/19642622/995714, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69026067/995714, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76983370/995714

Answer (score 0):

Put your ASCII Art in a file (without the leading `echo`). E.g. `myAsciiArt.txt`:

```
55555555555555 ...
...
... &&&&&&&&&&&&&&
```

And modify you batch script like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
:91
title 911 turbo
echo please turn on fullscreen and wait...
timeout 5
REM the following will echo the previously generated text file to the terminal
type myAsciiArt.txt
pause >nul
```

**Note 1:** I added `@ECHO OFF` to prevent the echoing of the commands
**Note 2:** Make sure to have the correct path to the file with the ASCII art
**Note 3:** I didn't question the broader meaning of your code
**Note 4:** I narrowed my eyes and questioned myself: Is it a Porsche 911?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I went deep into the other solution brought up by phuclv and compo and they seem to help with the problem. Yes it is a porsche 911.